# Javascript string comparison error

Tags: javascript, ajax, string, comparison

I have a problem with a piece of code that I use to check if a function returns a string that is equal to another string. The problem sounds trivial, but I cannot seem to get it to work.

Here is the code, and make sure you yell at me if you'll need any more code.

```
    <script>

    function emptyElement(x){
         _(x).innerHTML = "";
    }

    function login(){

        var e = _("email").value;
        var p = _("password").value;

        if(e == "" || p == "") {
            _("status").innerHTML = "Fill out all of the form data";
        } else{
            _("loginbtn").style.display = "none";
            _("status").innerHTML ='please wait...';
            var ajax = ajaxObj("POST", "index.php");
            ajax.onreadystatechange = function() {
            if(ajaxReturn(ajax) == true) {
                  document.write(ajax.responseText); // returns "login_failed" when I try it
                  if(ajax.responseText == "login_failed"){
                      _("status").innerHTML = "Login unsuccessful, please try again.";
                      _("loginbtn").style.display = "block";
                  } else {
                       //window.location = "afterlogin.php?u="+ajax.responseText;
            }           


        }
    }
    ajax.send("e="+e + "&p="+p);

      }
     }

     </script>
```

The window.location function is commented out for testing purposes. Don't mind that. Below, I will post code for the two scripts that are used, "main" and "ajax".

```
    function ajaxObj( meth, url ) {
         var x = new XMLHttpRequest();
         x.open( meth, url, true );
         x.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
         return x;
    }
    function ajaxReturn(x){
         if(x.readyState == 4 && x.status == 200){
              return true;  
         }
    }
```

And the code for main.js

```
    function _(x){
         return document.getElementById(x);
    }
```

I do not want to take credit for the original code; it is gathered from developphp.com and just altered slightly.

The problem is that, as I've commented, the line

```
ajax.responseText == "login_failed"
```

never seems to be true, not matter how I do. This is what I need guidance on.

Regards

Comment: Have you tried `ajax.responseText.indexOf("login_failed") > -1` ?

Comment: do console.log(ajax.responseText) to check what it contains.  Possible there's some whitespace appended/prepended to it.  If that's the case, try if (ajax.responseText.trim() == 'login_failed') ....

Comment: Are you in control of index.php? What exactly does it print out in case of a login error? have you tried `ajax.responseText.trim() == 'login_failed'` ?

Comment: Thanks for quick responses.

Yes, I am in charge of the index.php and yes, I have already tried the .trim() function, with no difference what so ever.

The problem seems to be that the javascript above handles all login attempts as successful logins, even though they are not. When I try this code, I do not even have a user in the database, so the login has to be wrong.

anguyen8, what does that piece of code do, exactly?

Answer (score 0):

> It's too late for the answer, but  someone may have the same issue.

**You need to write**

```
ajax.responseText == '"login_failed"';
```